# Occasional error when building an eclipse feature with a Tycho project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, tycho

I have a Maven/Tycho build of an OSGi based application that occasionally fails with an exception.

I have about 20 eclipse features, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual feature (it can be a different feature that fails every time, and often the build works fine)

It's no disaster, but I'd like the fix this at some point, and I don't really know how to debug this further short of diving into Tycho code or starting to mess with random settings.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

System: Fedora Linux
JVM: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (fedora-67.1.11.3.fc16-x86_64)
Maven:  3.0.3
Tycho: 0.15.0

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.15.0:package-feature (default-package-feature) on project com.dexels.navajo.tipi.swing.feature: Execution default-package-feature of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.15.0:package-feature failed: com.dexels.navajo:com.dexels.navajo.tipi.swing.deps:eclipse-plugin:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT does not provide an artifact with classifier 'null'
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-package-feature of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.15.0:package-feature failed: com.dexels.navajo:com.dexels.navajo.tipi.swing.deps:eclipse-plugin:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT does not provide an artifact with classifier 'null'
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.dexels.navajo:com.dexels.navajo.tipi.swing.deps:eclipse-plugin:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT does not provide an artifact with classifier 'null'
at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.FeatureXmlTransformer$1.visitPlugin(FeatureXmlTransformer.java:62)
at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.traversePlugin(AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.java:215)
at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.traverseFeature(AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.java:86)
at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.traverseFeature(AbstractArtifactDependencyWalker.java:63)
at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.FeatureXmlTransformer.transform(FeatureXmlTransformer.java:47)
at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackageFeatureMojo.expandVersionQualifiers(PackageFeatureMojo.java:300)
at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackageFeatureMojo.execute(PackageFeatureMojo.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
... 28 more
```

Comment: Did you found something? I'm facing the same issue, but always the same feature (reactor-build) and only occasionally. I'm using Debian with the Oracle JDK.

Comment: I'm afraid not in a constructive way. I've upgraded by build machine to the latest Apache CentOS, upgraded to Java 1.7 (IcedTea, I think) and I've upgraded to the latest tycho version. I haven't seen the problem since.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to

- the availability of the item in the local Maven repository and/or remote Maven repositories
- the build phase you are executing.

If the included eclipse-plugin has a version that is not in any Maven repositories, and you only execute the build up to a lifecycle phase which does not include install, you may be able to reproduce the problem.

If you manage to pin down the problem, this would make a good [bug report for Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=specific).

Comment: Tycho projects don't resolve via the Maven repo.  They use the p2 repo instead.